# Is there a convenient method to only save model architecture information in Pytorch to a protobuf ruled file?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, protocol-buffers, onnx

Is there a convenient method to only save model architecture information in Pytorch to a protobuf ruled file?

I know how to use `pytorch.save` to save both weights and net at the same time, to a dictionary structured data. But if I'd like to save the data to an isolated file which only contain the net architecture, like what Caffe did train from initial status, is that possible? The file may used in somewhere else. Does ONNX can do something sort of like that?